# Convert text file specifying links into an adjacency matrix

Tags: c++, graph-theory, shortest-path, dijkstra, getline

I am trying to make the Dijkstra algorithm to take input from the text file. I found this example (https://www.programiz.com/dsa/dijkstra-algorithm) for Dijkstra, which does exactly what I need - finds the shortest path between two nodes and prints it together with a cost.

How can I fill the graph from the given text file? Thanks in advance for any replies.

Code example, updated to use decimal weights:

```
// Dijkstra's Algorithm in C++

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <limits.h>

using namespace std;

void DijkstrasTest();

int main() {
  DijkstrasTest();
  return 0;
}

class Node;
class Edge;

void Dijkstras();
vector<Node*>* AdjacentRemainingNodes(Node* node);
Node* ExtractSmallest(vector<Node*>& nodes);
double Distance(Node* node1, Node* node2);
bool Contains(vector<Node*>& nodes, Node* node);
void PrintShortestRouteTo(Node* destination);

vector<Node*> nodes;
vector<Edge*> edges;

class Node {
   public:
  Node(char id)
    : id(id), previous(NULL), distanceFromStart(INT_MAX) {
    nodes.push_back(this);
  }

   public:
  char id;
  Node* previous;
  double distanceFromStart;
};

class Edge {
   public:
  Edge(Node* node1, Node* node2, double distance)
    : node1(node1), node2(node2), distance(distance) {
    edges.push_back(this);
  }
  bool Connects(Node* node1, Node* node2) {
    return (
      (node1 == this->node1 &&
       node2 == this->node2) ||
      (node1 == this->node2 &&
       node2 == this->node1));
  }

   public:
  Node* node1;
  Node* node2;
  double distance;
};

///////////////////
void DijkstrasTest() {
  Node* a = new Node('a');
  Node* b = new Node('b');
  Node* c = new Node('c');
  Node* d = new Node('d');
  Node* e = new Node('e');
  Node* f = new Node('f');
  Node* g = new Node('g');

  Edge* e1 = new Edge(a, c, 1.74);
  Edge* e2 = new Edge(a, d, 2.156);
  Edge* e3 = new Edge(b, c, 2.516);
  Edge* e4 = new Edge(c, d, 1.321);
  Edge* e5 = new Edge(b, f, 3.51);
  Edge* e6 = new Edge(c, e, 3.11);
  Edge* e7 = new Edge(e, f, 2.2);
  Edge* e8 = new Edge(d, g, 1.1);
  Edge* e9 = new Edge(g, f, 1.5);

  a->distanceFromStart = 0;  // set start node
  Dijkstras();
  PrintShortestRouteTo(f);
}

///////////////////

void Dijkstras() {
  while (nodes.size() > 0) {
    Node* smallest = ExtractSmallest(nodes);
    vector<Node*>* adjacentNodes =
      AdjacentRemainingNodes(smallest);

    const int size = adjacentNodes->size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
      Node* adjacent = adjacentNodes->at(i);
      double distance = Distance(smallest, adjacent) +
               smallest->distanceFromStart;

      if (distance < adjacent->distanceFromStart) {
        adjacent->distanceFromStart = distance;
        adjacent->previous = smallest;
      }
    }
    delete adjacentNodes;
  }
}

// Find the node with the smallest distance,
// remove it, and return it.
Node* ExtractSmallest(vector<Node*>& nodes) {
  int size = nodes.size();
  if (size == 0) return NULL;
  int smallestPosition = 0;
  Node* smallest = nodes.at(0);
  for (int i = 1; i < size; ++i) {
    Node* current = nodes.at(i);
    if (current->distanceFromStart <
      smallest->distanceFromStart) {
      smallest = current;
      smallestPosition = i;
    }
  }
  nodes.erase(nodes.begin() + smallestPosition);
  return smallest;
}

// Return all nodes adjacent to 'node' which are still
// in the 'nodes' collection.
vector<Node*>* AdjacentRemainingNodes(Node* node) {
  vector<Node*>* adjacentNodes = new vector<Node*>();
  const int size = edges.size();
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    Edge* edge = edges.at(i);
    Node* adjacent = NULL;
    if (edge->node1 == node) {
      adjacent = edge->node2;
    } else if (edge->node2 == node) {
      adjacent = edge->node1;
    }
    if (adjacent && Contains(nodes, adjacent)) {
      adjacentNodes->push_back(adjacent);
    }
  }
  return adjacentNodes;
}

// Return distance between two connected nodes
double Distance(Node* node1, Node* node2) {
  const int size = edges.size();
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    Edge* edge = edges.at(i);
    if (edge->Connects(node1, node2)) {
      return edge->distance;
    }
  }
  return -1;  // should never happen
}

// Does the 'nodes' vector contain 'node'
bool Contains(vector<Node*>& nodes, Node* node) {
  const int size = nodes.size();
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    if (node == nodes.at(i)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

///////////////////

void PrintShortestRouteTo(Node* destination) {
  Node* previous = destination;
  cout << "Distance from start: "
     << destination->distanceFromStart << endl;
  while (previous) {
    cout << previous->id << " ";
    previous = previous->previous;
  }
  cout << endl;
}

// these two not needed
vector<Edge*>* AdjacentEdges(vector<Edge*>& Edges, Node* node);
void RemoveEdge(vector<Edge*>& Edges, Edge* edge);

vector<Edge*>* AdjacentEdges(vector<Edge*>& edges, Node* node) {
  vector<Edge*>* adjacentEdges = new vector<Edge*>();

  const int size = edges.size();
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    Edge* edge = edges.at(i);
    if (edge->node1 == node) {
      cout << "adjacent: " << edge->node2->id << endl;
      adjacentEdges->push_back(edge);
    } else if (edge->node2 == node) {
      cout << "adjacent: " << edge->node1->id << endl;
      adjacentEdges->push_back(edge);
    }
  }
  return adjacentEdges;
}

void RemoveEdge(vector<Edge*>& edges, Edge* edge) {
  vector<Edge*>::iterator it;
  for (it = edges.begin(); it < edges.end(); ++it) {
    if (*it == edge) {
      edges.erase(it);
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

Fragment of the input file, number of lines is unknown:

```
source_id,target_id,weight
1,2,0.17
2,3,0.13
3,4,0.15
3,5,0.02
4,5,0.09
5,2,0.01
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? What do you not understand?

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is a place for asking **specific** programming questions. You may want to read this for further information: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/12149471)

Comment: Here are a lot of options to read a csv file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/how-can-i-read-and-parse-csv-files-in-c I'm not sure what your columns represent or how you would transform that data into Node objects, but perhaps it will get you started.

Comment: Thank you for your replies and sorry for misunderstanding. I tried to reformulate my post, hope it is better now.

Answer (score 1):

Your input is a list of node links.

Your algorithm requires an adjacency matrix, which is a vector containing vectors of the nodes adjacent to each node.

To convert from a list of links to an adjacency matrix, you need a graph class that among other things will populate the adjacency martrix using a function such as `AddLink( int src, int dst, double cost )`

There are many such classes available for you to copy or modify to your particular situation.  I'll mention just one: [PathFinder](https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder2)

Below is the PathFinder code to do the conversion.  You will need something slightly different to handle the format of your file.  [Here is the format](https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder2/wiki/Costs) that PathFinder is reading

```
while (std::getline(myFile, line))
    {
        std::cout << line << "\n";
        auto token = ParseSpaceDelimited(line);
        if (!token.size())
            continue;
        switch (token[0][0])
        {
        case 'g':
            if (myFinder.linkCount())
                throw std::runtime_error("cPathFinderReader:: g ( directed ) must occurr before any links");
            myFinder.directed();
            break;

        case 'l':
            if (weights && (token.size() != 4))
                throw std::runtime_error("cPathFinder::read bad link line");
            else if (3 > token.size() || token.size() > 4)
                throw std::runtime_error("cPathFinder::read bad link line");
            if (weights)
                cost = atof(token[3].c_str());
            else
                cost = 1;
            if (cost < maxNegCost)
                maxNegCost = cost;
            myFinder.addLink(
                token[1],
                token[2],
                cost);
            break;

        case 's':
            if (token.size() != 2)
                throw std::runtime_error("cPathFinder::read bad start line");
            myFinder.start(token[1]);
            break;

        case 'e':
            if (token.size() != 2)
                throw std::runtime_error("cPathFinder::read bad end line");
            myFinder.end(token[1]);
            break;
        }
    }
```